# It is possible that when closing an open connection java really not be closed?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, connection

I have connections in an application with Tomcat and SQL Server that remain open even though it is explicitly stated that they close java
Is this possible with some configuration in SQL Server?

Comment: How are you retrieving a connection, and which SQL Server driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your connection came from a connection pool, yes closing the connection will simply return the connection to the pool for another client to use. Connection pooling is more efficient when you have many short-lived connections.

Comment: ... and the cost of creating a connection is relatively high e.g. JDBC connections. +1

Comment: connections are made with pool with c3p0

Comment: But I found open connections when the code explicitly close (released into the pool)

Comment: That's what a pool does. The pool wraps connections that it gives to clients which alters the behavior of `Connection.close()`. Calling `Connection.close()` won't actually close the connection to SQL Server. If you don't want that behavior, don't use a connection pool, or destroy the pool when you're finished with it.